# How can I set Date value into cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

Following is my code:

```
String monthEndDate = "31-Dec-17";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy",java.util.Locale.ENGLISH);
XSSFCell updateDateCell = sheet.getRow(rownumber).getCell(15);
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)updateDateCell.getCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(
createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MMM-yy"));
Date updateDate = sdf.parse(monthEndDate);
updateDateCell.setCellValue(updateDate);
updateDateCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

It is setting numeric value **43100.0**

Comment: Where are you getting the numeric value 43100.0? In Excel's GUI view? This is not possible if the code, you are showing, runs without errors. Then the number format "dd-MMM-yy" **must** lead to a date view of the number. Of course the number 43100.0 **is** 31-Dec-17. 43100 days after 01-Jan-1900. This is how Excel stores date values.

Comment: yes, i am getting 43100.0 in Excel. can you please explain **number format "dd-MMM-yy" must lead to a date view of the number** . i didn't get it.

Comment: Then you need providing a complete example to show the problem. Because I have tried your code in a test case and my Excel shows 31-Dec-17, which is the number 43100 formatted using number format "dd-MMM-yy".

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that you are getting the `CellStyle` via `Cell.getCellStyle` and then you are overwriting that  `CellStyle`.

`CellStyle`s are in `Excel` defined on `Workbook` level. That means, not each cell has it's own cell style but cells share cell styles defined on workbook level.

So if you do the getting the `CellStyle` via `Cell.getCellStyle` and then overwriting that  `CellStyle` multiple times then only the last overwriting will be active. So I suspect, your complete code overwrites the same cell style, gotten from another cell, with another number format after you have overwritten it with the date number format.

The easy conclusion could be to really give each cell it's own cell style. But this is also wrong since there is a limit number of cell styles in a workbook. So we need

1. Having as much own cell styles as needed.
2. Having as much cell styles shared as possible.

To achieve this [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) can be used in `apache poi`. This provides methods only to create a new cell style if there is not already the same cell style defined in the workbook and simply to use that cell style if there is already the same cell style defined in the workbook.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ExcelSetDateValue {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelTest.xlsx"));

  //possiby we need data formats
  DataFormat dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();

  //get sheet and set row number
  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  int rownumber = 3;

  //get the date
  String monthEndDate = "31-Dec-17";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", java.util.Locale.ENGLISH);
  Date updateDate = sdf.parse(monthEndDate);

  //set date as cell value
  XSSFCell updateDateCell = sheet.getRow(rownumber).getCell(15);
  updateDateCell.setCellValue(updateDate);

  //use CellUtil to set the CellStyleProperties
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  properties.put(CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormat.getFormat("dd-MMM-yy"));
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(updateDateCell, properties);

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelTestNew.xlsx"));
  wb.close();
 }  
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a try to answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836373/apache-poi-excel-row-height-is-not-automatically-adjusting-in-libreoffice

Comment: @nantitv: See my comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Add `updateDateCell = Format(updateDateCell, "dd-MMM-yyyy")` at the end of your code.

You should get `31-Dec-2017`.

Comment: How shall the VBA function `Format` help in context `java` `apache poi` `xssf`? Does the code even looks like VBA for you? It is not, it is Java code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which I already have for formatting date, you can reuse the part of it ( I marked the relevant lines of code). It's tested and working fine, if any issue let me know.

//UPDATE 
Please see Axel Richter's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47920182/1053496 for the correct answer. In my example, I'm storing date as String instead of Date object which is not the recommended way

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class WriteExcelBasic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String excelFileName = "/Users/home/Test3.xls";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);


        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");
        XSSFFont urlFont = wb.createFont();
        style.setFont(urlFont);
        String monthEndDate = "31-Dec-17";
        DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat(); //these 3 lines  are enough
         short dateFormat = df.getFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); // 2nd 
        style.setDataFormat(dateFormat); // 3rd


        for (int r = 0; r < 1; r++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
            row.setHeight((short) -1);
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
                String ss = "31-Dec-17";
                cell.setCellValue(ss);
                    style.setWrapText(true);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
        }

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            wb.write(baos);
            byte[] myByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            fos.write(myByteArray);
            fos.flush();
        }
        finally {
            wb.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String ss = "31-Dec-17"; cell.setCellValue(ss);`: Your code is storing "31-Dec-17" as a string cell value instead a date. This is not recommended since then you cannot using this string in date functions of Excel in further usage.  @im_mangesh' s code is more correct in this way since it used `setCellValue` with a `Date`. This is the recommended way.

Comment: @AxelRichter you are right. I just consider the formatting angle. Thanks for pointing it out. I will update the answer accordingly